# Event OnChange doesn't work

Tags: jquery, onchange

I tried this, but nothing happens when I modify the input. 
Any idea?

```
<input type="text" id="date">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#date').change(function () {
    alert('Date changed');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The change event is only triggered when the input looses focus. Also, the `input` element does not have the ID `date`.

Comment: It's a mistake, I used "id", but it doesn't work. I have modified my code. And also when I click out of the input, nothing happens

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/P6pYw/1/. Or does this not work for you either?

Comment: Yes it works on this. Does it come from my configuration ? I use MAMP, what should I change ?

Comment: Do you import jquery correctly?

Comment: You don't even need a server at all in this case. You could open the HTML file directly in your browser. I'm afraid there is not much we can do since we cannot look at your computer. Maybe having a look at the console gives you an idea what's wrong, see [this article to learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: I have jquery 1.9.1 <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Any error in developer tool?

Answer (score 0):

Because you used `#` and not `.`

```
$('.date')
```

Comment: There is no character limit for answers. Please use proper words and not `u` for `you`.

Comment: @FelixKling I should have said this instead of editing myself :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that next time.

Comment: It's a mistake, I used "id", but it doesn't work. I have modified my code.

Answer (score 0):

The change event is triggered only when the focus on the textbox is lost, so you should use also the keyup event. Furthermore you use "#date", but as "date" is the class of your textbox, you should use ".date".

```
$('.date').change(function () {
    alert('Date changed');
  }).keyup(function(){$(this).change()});
```